# How to show all printed values when using arm-none-eabi-gdb?

Tags: arm, gdb, cortex-m

I'm debugging an ARM in VS Code using openocd, arm-none-eabi-gdb and cortex-debug.

When I try to print a formatted variable in the debug consol it hides duplicated values.
Is there a way to get all values printed on one line (as it is when using cppdbg) or at least not hide values. This hiding makes it impossible to copy and compare to a similar array from the matching unit test.

I do think it hides all identical lines and not only when using the print command.

See pictures below:

[Print values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hYPJ.png)
[Array list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro5om.png)

Comment: What is the output of the GDB command `show print repeats` ?

Comment: Threshold for repeated print elements is 10.